# dpm does not display form return values

Tags: debugging

I just enabled the devel module on Drupal 6 and using `dpm($form)` was showing values for me but  it does not show values any more. What would mostly the issue here? Is there a way to see those values?

Thanks

Comment: This is difficult issue to help you with if you're not providing any code or a specific context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical cases for why a `dpm(...)` doesn't show up:

- Cache: The `dpm()` is in some cached code and is not actually being executed.
- Access: You are viewing the page with a user that doesn't have access to see the debug messages.
- Ajax/etc: Some code clears the messages before they are rendered, in this case you can use `dd()` to print to a log file instead.

Comment: Also sometimes while putting dpm() in theme part, it may not be executed while kpr() will.

Answer (score 1):

In say a validation function, to see both the `$form` structure and what the user has entered, use a devel debug statement like:

```
dpm(array('$form' => $form, '$form_state' => $form_state), "Validation debug");
```

The `$form_state['values']` array will contain the raw user entries you can then access and validate.